# What does <faultstring>Error processing input</faultstring> mean when trying to call webservice using PL/SQL?

Tags: web-services, soap, plsql, wsdl, soapui

I am trying to call a web service wsdl. I get correct response in SoapUI. However, when I call programatially using pl/sql I am getting following error:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
   <soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Error processing input</faultstring>
     <detail>
      <OracleErrors xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/faults">
       <OracleError>
        <ErrorNumber>ORA-31011</ErrorNumber>
        <Message><![CDATA[XML parsing failed]]></Message>
      </OracleError>
      </OracleErrors>
     </detail>
   </soap:Fault>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I use the same request that works fine in SoapUI.

Please let me understand what the error means. Is this error on the webservice or on the call that I have in the procedure. It passes the authentication, so I know the call was made.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its working well in SOAP UI then there's no problem on the web service, Once you trigger the call from SOAP UI check for the `http log` tab

Check if you are passing all the details as a part of the procedure

[image]

The devil is in the detail

Comment: I copied exactly what was listing in the SOAP UI and it works now.